# FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-166

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to toast values in callscreen. This is my `phonestate` class, which extends `phonestatelistener`. Inside this I have created a thread class like this:

```
class Test extends Thread implements Runnable {
private CustomPhoneStateListener parent;

ThreadProg() {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("come to run");
    con = db.getHmsConnection();
    String query = "select name,Phone,message from contactdetails where Phone='"
            + incomingNumber1 + "'";
    resVec = ut.multipleElemInSingleVector(query, con);
    System.out.println("the vector values " + resVec);
    msg = resVec.get(2).toString();
    System.out.println("message :" + msg);

    // Alert.msgbox("alert", "alert", msg, 1);

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming number :" + msg,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
};

}
```

Exception is as follows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-166  java.lang.NullPointerException  at 
>   com.example.test.CustomPhoneStateListener$ThreadProg.run(CustomPhoneStateListener.java:123)

I refered google and found that to use the `asynctask` class but I don't know how to use the `asynctask` class by extending `threadprog`. besides it's already extending the `thread` class.
I just want to toast that value, that's it.

android version more than 3.0

Comment: where you are writing this code? inside activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this, as follows. Note that I wrote this without an IDE, so there might be some issues. I'd also advise to use Androids build-in Log system.

```
new ProgAsyncTask().execute();

private class ProgAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG = "ProgAsyncTask"; // Tag used in log msgs
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "come to run");
        con = db.getHmsConnection();
        String query = "select name,Phone,message from contactdetails where Phone='" + incomingNumber1 + "'";
        resVec = ut.multipleElemInSingleVector(query, con);
        Log.d(TAG, "the vector values "+resVec);
        msg = resVec.get(2).toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "message :" + msg);
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming number :" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```